# Symfony API Platform how to perform custom change of value before entity return/flush while PATCH

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

1. Let's say I have Entity (TestEntity123) and there are in ApiResource annotation defined itemOperations and one of these is called "patch".
2. I want to perform PATCH request where ID ("api/customEntpoind/{id}") of entity is defined in URL while in request body I have defined myCustomParameter:
   `{ "myCustomParameter": "654" }`
3. I want for this endpoint with this particular parameter sent to perform for example editation of entity attribute by this parameter, let's say for example addition (current entity value patched by request parameter)

How can I achieve this please? I have tried usage of custom controller, transformer, input and output classes, neither seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I hope you have somehow solved it or no more need it. But if you still need help., please provide some code snippet what you are exactly doing. Seems like it can be very easily done by custom controllers but without having a better and clear view, it is difficult to say.

Comment: @StiffRoy I have used configuration for endpoint according to this source: https://apidog.com/blog/use-swagger-php-to-create-swagger-documentation/.

Comment: So I defined itemOperations, there I set endpoint operation, with these attributes: method, name, path, controller, requirements (my both parameters),  openapi_context (with parameters definition using attributes: name, in, required, descriptoin, schema (and its attribute is type)).

Answer (score 0):

So I defined itemOperations, there I set endpoint operation, with these attributes: method, name, path, controller, requirements (my both parameters), openapi_context (with parameters definition using attributes: name, in, required, descriptoin, schema (and its attribute is type)).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).